# Replace Nan with 0 at where feature is missing in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a dataset with missing values. The head of the dataset looks like this:

```
+1 1:0.2 2:0.7 3:-1.2 4:0.5
-1 1:0.9 3:0.1 4:0.8
-1 1:-0.1 2:0.1 4:1.0
+1 2:0.6 3:-1.0
```

The first column is the label of the data, and the number in front of the colon is the index of the feature. Some features are missing at some rows. So when I import the data using the following code,

```
df = pandas.read_csv('dataset',header=None,sep = '\s+|:',engine='python',dtype=float)
```

I get a dataframe looks like

```
    0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
0   1.0     1.0     0.2     2.0     0.7     3.0     -1.2    4.0     0.5
1   -1.0    1.0     0.9     3.0     0.1     4.0     0.8     NaN     NaN
2   -1.0    1.0     -0.1    2.0     0.1     4.0     1.0     NaN     NaN
3   1.0     2.0     0.6     3.0     -1.0    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

I want to replace the NaNs with 0s in the correct place. But if I use `df.fillna(0)`, I will replace the NaN at the end of each row, which looks like

```
    0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
0   1.0     1.0     0.2     2.0     0.7     3.0     -1.2    4.0     0.5
1   -1.0    1.0     0.9     3.0     0.1     4.0     0.8     0.0     0.0
2   -1.0    1.0     -0.1    2.0     0.1     4.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
3   1.0     2.0     0.6     3.0     -1.0    0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

What I really want is a dataframe looks like this,

```
    0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
0   1.0     1.0     0.2     2.0     0.7     3.0     -1.2    4.0     0.5
1   -1.0    1.0     0.9     0.0     0.0     3.0     0.1     4.0     0.8
2   -1.0    1.0     -0.1    2.0     0.1     0.0     0.0     4.0     1.0
3   1.0     0.0     0.0     2.0     0.6     3.0     -1.0    0.0     0.0
```

So after I drop the index I should have

```
    0       1       2       3       4     
0   1.0     0.2     0.7     -1.2    0.5
1   -1.0    0.9     0.0     0.1     0.8
2   -1.0    -0.1    0.1     0.0     1.0
3   1.0     0.0     0.6     -1.0    0.0
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. You say you want to replace the NaNs with 0, but you say that `fillna(0)` replaces the NaNs with 0, and you don't want that. Are you instead looking for `dropna(axis=1)`?

Comment: Can you double check your df you posted under "What I really want is a dataframe to that looks like this"? Not sure how you went from 9 -> 5 columns

Comment: @CapnJack, also different values in some of the columns

Comment: @G.Anderson, Hopefully OP updates the example. : /

Comment: @BrianJoseph, that sounds like `dropna()` with extra steps. Looking at he values, it seems like OP wants to shift values from the ends of the rows into earlier columns...flagged for being unclear

Comment: @G.Anderson I edited the question by adding some inter-steps.

Comment: I think in each row of input the number in front of the `:` is supposed to be the correct column for the value after it, so `pandas.read_csv` is probably the problem here.

Comment: @BurningKarl, I think you nailed it. Serious X/Y problem on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with filling N/A values, as @BurningKarl suggested in the comments, the problem is trying to read in file with `read_csv` that isn't in any way a csv or csv-like file. You will likely need to parse this file differently.

If it helps you get started, I have posted a snippet below that shows how to get the data formatted to ingest into a proper dataframe, according to what you say you need. If you can parse your file with `file.readlines` into a list of dictionaries, you can just wrap that in a DataFrame constructor. (Note, this parsing will likely take some effort to get it exactly right)

```
x=[{0:1,1:0.2, 2:0.7, 3:-1.2, 4:0.5},
{0:-1,1:0.9, 3:0.1, 4:0.8},
{0:-1,1:-0.1, 2:0.1, 4:1.0},
{0:1,2:0.6, 3:-1.0}]

pd.DataFrame(x)
```

gives you

```
    0    1       2      3       4
0   1    0.2     0.7    -1.2    0.5
1   -1   0.9     NaN    0.1     0.8
2   -1   -0.1    0.1    NaN     1.0
3   1    NaN     0.6    -1.0    NaN
```

and then you can just fillna(0) as you tried before

Comment: I used `csv.reader` instead of `readlines` and followed your suggestion, and it works.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Don't forget to accept the answer if you feel like it's warranted.